# Wireless vibration sensor

Tags: wireless, sensor, bluetooth, arduino, xbee

I have a raspberry pi and I want to connect a vibration sensor. The connection to the sensor should be wireless. I want to have approximately a range from 30m up to 100m.

What would be a low price configuration to do that? What do I need? I have the raspberry already and a low price vibration sensor. So I need a module for the sensor with embedded ad-converter. And the module need a wireless connection. On the other side the raspberry also need a wireless connection module to connect both modules together.

I thougt about xbee or bluetooth. Xbee is very expensive I think. But the range is super and the size is also very small. And the xbee board has already a build in ad converter.

Which low price and "small" size setup could you recommend? Which trade offs are there with such a solution?

Answer (score 1):

http://r.ebay.com/u5QbBJ

I'm sure you can handle the wiring and coding.

Comment: Oh, that seems really cheap. Do you know that board? What do you think is the range of such a board? Do I get some documentation for coding with that board?

Comment: @CPA Says on the page it's 1000m with line-of-sight (probably a hundred indoors). A quick search yielded this datasheet: https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/Si4430-31-32.pdf

Comment: @CPA Here's some product info: http://www.electrodragon.com/product/si4432-433m-wireless-transceiver-module-distance-1500m/

Comment: @CPA Looks like it uses the SPI interface. I think reading the datasheet for the SPI commands and whipping up some code for it would do.